# ejabberd benchmarks and performance

Tags: performance, benchmark, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm considering to use XMPP for messaging platform (not a chat, I'd rather use it as a transport protocol) for communicating one to one, one to many between custom clients and I think I will extensively use channels.

Can someone share some information about ejabbered performance, are there any benchmarks on how many clients (and how many channels) can be safely connected to this server? What I’m looking for is between tens of thousands to hundreds of thousands of clients.

Comment: There's no real answer for what you're looking for. We don't know how you'd use the server exactly, so any benchmarks or numbers we could throw out might have no significance to your usage model. The only way to know would be to setup a test environment and see what it can do.

Comment: Understand, but are there any information how many simultaneous connection can be maintained by ejabberd single instance on some specific configuration. Any information would be helpful.

Comment: if the clients were all completely inactive, a 5 year old desktop could handle tens of thousands or possibly hundreds. Or one insanely active client could flood big iron. You're question is something akin to "how much water can I get through a hose"; if the hose is an ice-maker water line, not much; garden hose, more; 6" fire hose can do tons of water... I understand you think you're asking a simple question, but it's not.